# How to calculate/estimate the median value of multiple arrays?

Tags: statistics, median

I have multiple groups of numbers (Arrays):

```
Array 1 = {X1,X2,X3,...,Xn}
Array 2 = {Y1,Y2,Y3,...,Yn}
Array 3 = {Z1,Z2,Z3,...,Zn}
```

Where the values are unknown, and the size of each array might be different and <s>unknown</s> KNOWN.

You are given the MAX, MIN and the median values of each array.

How can you estimate with accuracy, the global median value of all the values of the arrays?

Comment: Perhaps provide some context?  What have you tried?

Comment: Tried the formula of calculating the median of grouped data, like the one mentioned here: https://www.themathdoctors.org/finding-the-median-of-grouped-data/
But in my case it didn't work, because i didn't know what is the frequency F, didn't know what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can't estimate this with good accuracy. Suppose you are given that:

- The min, max, and median of array 1 is $0$. Array 1 is size $1$.
- The min, max, and median of array 2 is $0$. Array 2 is size $1$.
- For array $3$ the min is $1$, the max is $10^{100}$, and the median is $10^{100}$. Array 3 is size $5$.

Then, we know array 3 is $\{1, X, 10^{100}, 10^{100}, 10^{100}\}$ for some $X$ between $1$ and $10^{100}$. The combined array would be $\{0, 0, 1, X,10^{100}, 10^{100}, 10^{100}\}$

The global median would be $X$, which could be any number between $1$ and a googol, and with the information we have we can't make any better guess!

Comment: However if you can assume that the values are roughly evenly distributed within the intervals, you can use the technique explained here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/frequency-grouped-mean-median-mode.html

Comment: In my case i don't think i can guarantee that the value are evenly distributed or not even close to that, but i find your answer and the link very helpful.
There's just one thing i'd like to clarify, what does frequency mean in this sort of calculation, can you give me an example of that formula with frequency? Thank you so much

Comment: @4R4C81D I believe in this context, frequency means how many data points are inside some interval. Here, you can find which interval contains the median, and that's the one you use in the formula.